# Converting all the final letters of numbers (all contained in a list of tuples) in a number

Tags: python, list, graph, tuples

This is a sample of a very big list of tuples, i want to create a graph with it but i can't because in many numbers there is a final undesired letter 'L'.

How can i change it or delete it?

```
my_list=[(2496989087L, [114762303, 4046411357L, 3350679909L, 228860861]),(936533587, [1968901658, 2228506255L, 788861322, 3157824057L])]
```

I tried in this way (wanted to change 'L' with '0') but it didn't work:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if (repr(my_list[i][0])[-1])!=0:
        (repr(my_list[i][0])[-1])=0
    if (repr(my_list[i][1])[-1])!=0:
        (repr(my_list[i][1])[-1])=0
print my_list
```

Comment: That is `L` for long, `print my_list[0][0] ->2496989087`, it makes no difference

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: @TobiMarg, the print should answer that question

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I missed this somehow.
AlessandroGallo thanks.

Comment: @AlessandroGallo, if your code errors then you need to ask a new question , don't edit and change your original question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'll make a new question, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just proceed graphing, the L stands for long and will not be a problem.

Comment: I assumed that L was the problem, in this case i write:  1) graph = nx.Graph()    2)    graph.add_edges_from(my_list)    and i receive this error:     TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'